# Add custom path to url to specific pages

Tags: menus, url-rewriting, paths

Right now all pages path like `/faq/` or `/about/`. I need path like `/home/faq/` `/home/about`. I tried change url slug in edit page. But Wordpress change my `home/faq` to `home-faq`.

I installed plugin `Create And Assign Categories For Pages` And add custom categories, but paths don't changed.

How can I do this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the permalink structure for all Pages (i.e. posts of the `page` type), you can use the `WP_Rewrite::$page_structure` property like so:

```php
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_382911' );
function wpse_382911() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->page_structure = 'home/%pagename%';
}
```

Don't forget to flush the rewrite rules — just visit the permalink settings admin page (`wp-admin` → Settings → Permalinks).

But if you just want that structure for specific pages, then how about just using the parent-child feature whereby you'd create the `home` page and make the `faq` and `about` pages as children of the `home` page?

Comment: Thank you) Parent page is solution. Very simple :)